# Exception getting JSON in Android app

Tags: android, json

I'm working on an Android app that gets JSON from a webserver then shows the data in a chart.

This is the log cat, could any one explain what is the error ?

```
10-28 02:30:01.653: D/gralloc_goldfish(5043): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-28 02:30:04.393: D/AndroidRuntime(5043): Shutting down VM
10-28 02:30:04.393: W/dalvikvm(5043): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not     execute method of the activity
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at     android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043): Caused by:     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at     android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3034)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     ... 11 more
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at android.graph.LineGraph.getIntent(LineGraph.java:27)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     at android.graph.GraphAChartEngineActivity.lineGraphHandler(GraphAChartEngineActivity.java:35)
10-28 02:30:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(5043):     ... 14 more
10-28 02:30:07.945: I/Process(5043): Sending signal. PID: 5043 SIG: 9
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what exactly is the error, but my guess would be with the code related to LineGraph.java (line 27) class as the NullPointerException seems to be raised from there.

Comment: Show the code that is being run when you click the `Button`

Comment: Do **NOT** put code in an `android.` package, unless you are working on the operating system itself. There are an infinite number of other package names to use -- choose one.